# Compose Navigation, intent filter with query parameters doesn't match

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I have an existing deep link:

`https://my-website.com/venue?id=12345`

Which I'm trying to handle. I've setup my intent filter as

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
    <data android:host="my-website.com" />
    <data android:pathPattern="/venue" />

</intent-filter>
```

And in my navigation host I have:

```
    composable(
        route = "$venueDetailsNavigationRoute/{$venueIdArg}",
        deepLinks = listOf(
            navDeepLink { uriPattern = "https://my-website.com/venue?id={$venueIdArg}" }
        ),
        arguments = listOf(
            navArgument(venueIdArg) { type = NavType.StringType }
        )
    ) {
        ....
    }
```

I've in a validation for this URL:

```
<tools:validation testUrl="https://my-website.com/venue?id=ChIJCxOkYUQddkgR7CM6A050bJ4" />
```

And this is coming back as valid.

But when I try and run

`adb shell am start -d https://my-website.com/venue?id=123`

it comes back with no matches.

but if I do `adb shell am start -d https://my-website.com/venue/123`

with a changed URL in my navigation host

```
"https://my-website.com/venue/{$venueIdArg}"
```

it works fine, but the problem is with this existing URL that I cannot change. Everything I'm reading says that this should work, but I just can't find my problem.